# i need help with a jquery plugin im making

Tags: jquery, plugins

im trying to make an easy drop down menu plugin for jquery but for some reason i cant get it to work, will someone help me? im new to plugins.

http://jsfiddle.net/twvd4/

i want the plugin to work like this below, but it isnt working at all

http://jsfiddle.net/cZe5x/

Comment: Could you possibly isolate the problem or specify what you need help with?

Comment: im sorry for not clearifying. i want a menu to slide down when i hover over an li, i have an example here http://jsfiddle.net/cZe5x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/twvd4/2/

First you named your plugin wrong: `jDropIt` vs `jDroptIt`.

Second you called the plugin before it was even attachted to the `$.fn`.

Comment: This looks quite awful in Firefox 4, many issues. Not your fault, it was that way before. Among other things, the backgrounds are all off, the submenus align left always, and the animation should really be stopped on mouseout. But technically it works.

Comment: thank you jerone, i will look into what you changed so i can learn from it.

Comment: Yeah your right Wesley. I havent looked at it in Firefox yet; but in Chrome it works how i wanted it too. ill look into that as well.